# Экранизация в laravel 5 / Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, laravel

Подскажите, 
в  laravel 5.4/Postgresql 9.4 хочу сделать поиск по like регистронезависимым :

```
        $quoteModel->where( 'LOWER(name)',  'like', "LOWER( 'str') ");
```

И получаю ошибку из-за  без экранизации

```
 "LOWER(name)" like LOWER('%sing%')
```

Как убрать   экранизацию и не нарушать  безопастнность ?
Или есть лучшее решение?

Спасибо!

Comment: Это называется **экранирование**.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка не в экранизации, а в том что вы указали что у вас колонка называется "LOWER(name)", используйте метод `whereRaw` взамен:

```
$quoteModel->whereRaw("LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('str')");
```

А лучше используйте регистронезависимый поиск:

```
$quoteModel->where('name', 'ilike', 'str');
```

Comment: А существует ли аналог ilike для обычного сравнения "="?

Comment: не припомню я такого